# Change activity after login

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, firebase-authentication

I was using Navigation drawer activity which has 4 fragments apart from MainActivity I used to use `displaySelectedScreen(R.id.nav_home);` to open Home fragment.

Now I'm using firebase email and password authentication in an empty activity, after successful authentication I am using this block of code to open MainActivity which already has `displaySelectedScreen(R.id.nav_home);` and expecting it to open my Home fragment :D

```
private void loginApp() {
    //To switch activity after successful authentication!
    Intent mainIntent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(mainIntent);
    finish();
}
```

But app crashes :(

as I'm using onStart() to check if the user is already logged in, I'm unable to restart the app as its trying to change activity and is failing to do so. :'D

> I'm calling `loginApp()` twice, first time if the user is already logged in and the second time after successful authentication.

Comment: Show what error you are getting

Comment: it says, unfortunately, myapp has stopped.

Comment: Please post code, and the logcat of the crash